# Cannot access attribute that is a directive inside another directive's template

Tags: angularjs, node.js, file-upload, angularjs-directive

My custom directive is "testapp". I would like to access the value of "file-model" in its template, which would contain the file object to be uploaded. Whatever I do am not able to get the value, its displaying "undefined". Please suggest ways to solve this problem.

```
app.directive('testapp', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            text: '@',
            filem: '=fileModel'             
        },
        require:'fileModel',
        replace:true,
        template: '<div class="col-xs-4" style="padding-left:0px"><div class ="jumbotron" id="Section1"><input type="text" name="id" id="section{{incr}}" placeholder="Section Heading" class="form-control"><form id="addLIForm1"><div ng-repeat="i in range(fileIncr) track by $index"><input type="text"  name="file{{incr}}{{$index+1}}" id="file{{incr}}{{$index+1}}"  class="form-control" placeholder="File Name" style="width:50%" ><input type = "file"  id="path{{incr}}{{$index+1}}" file-model = "file{{incr}}{{$index+1}}"></div></form><a id="addMore" ng-click="addfile()" href="#">Add More File</a><a id="addMoreSec1" ng-click="add()" class="pull-right" href="#" ng-show="showValue">Add More Section</a></div></div>',
        controller: function ($scope, $element,$window) {

            $scope.incr=$window.globalIncr;
            $scope.fileIncr=$window.globalfileIncr;
            $scope.showValue=$window.globalsectionValue;
            $scope.add = function () {
                $window.globalsectionValue=false;
                $window.globalIncr+=1;
                $window.globalfileIncr=1;
                var el = $compile("<testapp></testapp>")($scope);
                $element.parent().append(el);
                //alert($window.globalfileIncr);
                //alert($element.parent().parent());
            };

            $scope.range=function(n)
            {
                return new Array(n);
            }

            $scope.addfile=function(){
            alert($scope.filem);

                $scope.fileIncr+=1;
                $window.counterObject[$scope.incr] = $scope.fileIncr;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Do you mean that you are expecting markup like `<testapp><file-model>...</file-model></testapp>`, or `<testapp file-model="..."></testapp>`?

Comment: @GregL thanks for the reply. But, i want to access the file-model which i going to use for upload..

Comment: Okay, so tell me more about what file-model is. It is not clear from what you have so far.

Comment: app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
 return {restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
   var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
   var modelSetter = model.assign;
   element.bind('change', function(){
    scope.$apply(function(){
     modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
     console.log(attrs.value);console.log("ele"+element[0].files[0]);console.log("ele111"+JSON.stringify(modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]),null,"    "));});});}};}]);

Comment: app.service('fileUpload',['$http', function ($http) {
 this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('file', file);
  $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
   transformRequest: angular.identity,
   headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
  })
  .success(function(){
   alert('success upload');
  })
  .error(function(){
   alert("File Upload error");
  });
 }
}]);

Comment: first is the directive used which will receive the file and store the as file object in file-model and the second is service for uploading file.

Comment: Can you create a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co) with all of the relevant code you have so far? It is not sufficient to have code like that in comments. Make sure to show how you wish to use this directive.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/WtmAFPZH5HC6Yl5eUDlG?p=catalogue